# Google Api Response Distance Value in standard format

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance

At the moment i'm returning the distance from the route as follows:

```
        var Distance = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
        alert(Distance);
```

Atm the moment the value sometimes returns the value in KiloMeters and sometimes in Meters depending on the values.Is it possible to return this values always as kilometers?

Comment: What does the request look like? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value`.  That will always be meters.

[From the documentation for google.maps.Distance object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Distance)

Properties  Type    Description

text    string  A string representation of the distance value, using the UnitSystem specified in the request.

**value**   number  **The distance in meters**.